# dotnet-gcdump error : Process 1 not running compatible .NET runtime

Tags: .net, kubernetes

I have a .Net 7 API thats runs as a background service and it is running on tanzu kubernetes environment. I have installed dotnet-gcdump but when I try to execute a dump (after exec into pod) using :

```
./dotnet-gcdump collect -p 1 -o sample1
```

I am getting an error :

```
 0.0s: Creating type table flushing task
0.0s: [Error] Exception during gcdump: Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.ServerNotAvailableException: Process 1 not running compatible .NET runtime.
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.PidIpcEndpoint.GetDefaultAddress() in /_/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client/DiagnosticsIpc/IpcTransport.cs:line 282
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.PidIpcEndpoint.Connect(TimeSpan timeout) in /_/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client/DiagnosticsIpc/IpcTransport.cs:line 243
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.IpcClient.SendMessageGetContinuation(IpcEndpoint endpoint, IpcMessage message) in /_/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client/DiagnosticsIpc/IpcClient.cs:line 40
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.EventPipeSession.Start(IpcEndpoint endpoint, IEnumerable`1 providers, Boolean requestRundown, Int32 circularBufferMB) in /_/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client/DiagnosticsClient/EventPipeSession.cs:line 34
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.DiagnosticsClient.StartEventPipeSession(IEnumerable`1 providers, Boolean requestRundown, Int32 circularBufferMB) in /_/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client/DiagnosticsClient/DiagnosticsClient.cs:line 70
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tools.GCDump.EventPipeSessionController..ctor(Int32 pid, List`1 providers, Boolean requestRundown) in /_/src/Tools/dotnet-gcdump/DotNetHeapDump/EventPipeDotNetHeapDumper.cs:line 235
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tools.GCDump.EventPipeDotNetHeapDumper.DumpFromEventPipe(CancellationToken ct, Int32 processID, MemoryGraph memoryGraph, TextWriter log, Int32 timeout, DotNetHeapInfo dotNetInfo) in /_/src/Tools/dotnet-gcdump/DotNetHeapDump/EventPipeDotNetHeapDumper.cs:line 52
```

The Dockerfile for the API is generated dynamically in Gitlab CI using the following script :

```
.generate_dockerfile:


script: |
    echo "checking dockerfile existence"
    if ! [ -e Dockerfile ]; then 
    echo "dockerfile doesn't exist. Trying to create a new dockerfile from csproj."
    pwd
    cd ./src
    echo "$PWD"
    docker_entrypoint=$(grep -m 1 AssemblyName $PWD/*.csproj | sed -r 's/\s*<[^>]*>//g' | sed -r 's/\r$//g').dll
    echo "${docker_entrypoint}"
    cat > Dockerfile << EOF
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
    RUN wget -O sdk_install.sh https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
    RUN chmod 777 sdk_install.sh
    RUN ./sdk_install.sh -c 7.0
    RUN cd /root/.dotnet
    RUN /root/.dotnet/dotnet tool install --global dotnet-gcdump
    RUN echo $PATH
    RUN export ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
    RUN echo $PATH
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY ./publish .
    
    ENTRYPOINT dotnet $docker_entrypoint
    EOF
    echo "dockerfile created"
    else
    echo "dockerfile exists"
    fi
```

When I run `./dotnet-gcdump --version`  I get :

```
7.0.410101+f9938321xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And when I run `./dotnet --info` I get :

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.202
 Commit:    6c74320bc3

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  11
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.11-x64
 Base Path:   /root/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.202/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.4
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       0a396acafe

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.202 [/root/.dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.4 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.4 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the process ID  - i was passing in a wrong process ID.

You have to check the process ID of the dotnet DLL (main process) before running the dump with :

```
cd /root/.dotnet/tools
./dotnet-gcdump ps
```

./dotnet-gcdump ps lists all the processes running in the container , with their corresponding ID like in the example output below:

```
./dotnet-gcdump ps
 6  dotnet  /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet  dotnet MyAPP.Core.MyAPI.dll
```